# Guardar datos de formulario combobox en archivo de texto desde vb

Tags: vb.net, vb

Hice un formulario, las respuestas posibles están en combobox, quiero guardar los items seleccionados en un archivo de txt que ya creé pero marca error ya que es inaccesible debido a su nivel de protección.Alguna idea de qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

```
Public TXT As StreamWriter

    Public numero_ses As String = "numero"


    Public Sub Crear_archivo() 

        Try
            TXT = File.CreateText("C:\DatosVB\" & numero_ses & ".txt")
        Catch
        End Try
TXT.WriteLine("sexo: " & rsexo.SelectedItem)
TXT.WriteLine("sexo: " & rpais.SelectedItem)
TXT.WriteLine("sexo: " & redad.SelectedItem)
TXT.WriteLine("sexo: " & redcivil.SelectedItem)
End Sub

Public Sub cerrar_archivo() 

        TXT.WriteLine() 
TXT.WriteLine("END OF THE SESSION")
        TXT.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Que quiere decir no me funciona? no se crea el archivo? no guarda nada? tira un error? la frase no me funciona es muy amplia.. usa el boton [edit] y aclara que pasa realmente...

Comment: muchas gracias @gbianchi espero que sea mas clara mi pregunta

Comment: Cual es el error exacto? No tenes permisos en esa carpeta?

Comment: no son carpetas, rsexo, rpais etc son los nombres de los combobox

Comment: Ese procedimiento esta fuera del formularioa que tiene esos co.bos? Esos combos estan como publicos o privados???

Comment: no, esta dentro del mismo formulario. Solo los puse en el formulario y agregué cada item desde el menú de propiedades, como modifico si son publicos o privados? Lo siento, soy totalmente novata

Comment: podes por favor poner el error que sale completo? nada de lo que decis tiene mucho sentido.. si estuviera en el mismo formulario no tendrias ese error...

Comment: Claro, aquí está lo que me aparece en la lista de errores
Error1 'rpais' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Error3'redcivil' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. Error2 'redad' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: pero ese error solo se da cuando tratas de acceder a elementos de un formulario desde afuera, y estos estan privados... falta mucha informacion y tu codigo para que quede claro de donde sale ese error...

Comment: los combos tienen esos nombres????

Comment: Si, esos son los nombres de los combos. Literalmente solo agregué los combos a la forma, les di nombre y en el menu de propiedades agregué cada item. No puse nada de código dando click sobre ellos

Comment: Y en donde escribiste el codigo? Mostras todo el codigo del formulario?

Comment: No, antes de lo que puse está 
````
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Cuestionario()

    End Sub

    Sub Cuestionario()
        titulo.Visible = True

    End Sub
(Aqui la parte del código que escribí arriba y luego una subrutina para que el formulario deje de ser visible)

Comment: Edita la publicacion y pone toda la info ahi